# How to verify doubles are enabled and working inside cuda?

Tags: cuda

I was looking to find out if double precision is enabled on my CUDA device or not since it is a Compute Capability 2.0 device with CUDA runtime 4.0(SDK & toolkit, latest driver).

How can I verify if double precision is activated or not? Also, I am getting warnings while compiling my CUDA code:
"double precision not supported, demoting to float" when clearly 2.0 devices support double precision natively. Why is this warning there then? Can anyone help as to what is going on here?
Is this warning coming because the default Makefile compiles for all possible architectures and this output is coming from compilation for lower architectures?

Answer (score 2):

The warning occurs because `nvcc` defaults to generating code for compute capability 1.0 devices which do not support double precision. If you add `-arch=sm_20` to your compile statements, `nvcc` will generate code for compute 2.0 devices, which includes native double precision floating point operations.